# An inconsistency was detected during an internal operation in database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

When I execute query

```
 Select * from TableName
```

I get this error :

An inconsistency was detected during an internal operation in database 'MYDABATADASE'(ID:5) on page (1:4796). Please contact technical support. Reference number 7.

How can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 6):

Try to [run](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2152734/en-us) [**DBCC CHECKDB**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx) and after it ends try to analyse the output (output will suggest you user actions required to fix the issues) or (and) try to restore your DB from the last known good backup.

```
DBCC CHECKDB('YOUR_DB_NAME') WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS
```

There are two repair options that **DBCC CHECKDB** output can suggest

- **REPAIR_REBUILD** - performs a repair that does not lead to any data
  loss.
- **REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS** - performs a repair and fixes the
  corrupted database structures, and also may results in data loss

After deciding which option to use (suppose you chose second) you need to execute code similar to this:

```
ALTER DATABASE [YOUR_DB_NAME] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    DBCC CHECKDB ('YOUR_DB_NAME', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS);
    ALTER DATABASE [YOUR_DB_NAME] SET MULTI_USER;
COMMIT;
```

*Note that SQLDUMPnnnn.txt is created in the SQL Server LOG directory and contains the results of the DBCC CHECKDB command and additional diagnostic output. ([source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx))*